# How do I query the "expiryDate" field within an array of objects when the objects do not have a field name?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with a JSON file containing objects structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "65143f76653355483f68981d" },
    "date": "2023-09-27",
    "certificates": [
      { "cnv2234": { "expiryDate": "2024-08-17" } },
      { "crs14359": { "expiryDate": "2023-09-14" } },
      { "crs14359": { "expiryDate": "2030-03-06" } },
      { "crs14359": { "expiryDate": "2040-02-25" } }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've attempted various queries, such as:

```
query = { "certificates.expiryDate": { "$lte": "2023-09-14" } }
query = { "certificates": { "$elemMatch": { "expiryDate": { "$lte": "2023-09-14" } } } }
query = { "certificates": { "$elemMatch": { "expiryDate": { "$lte": "2023-09-14" } } } }
```

None of these queries have returned any data. While I can successfully retrieve all data and iterate through each host and date individually, this is not practical for larger datasets. Can someone guide me on how to correct this query for efficient filtering based on "expiryDate" within an array of objects when the objects do not have a field name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to consider for your current schema and it is recommended that you refactor it.

1. Dates are stored in strings. Dates should be stored as proper date objects for querying.
2. Currently dynamic values are used as field names. Refactor the schema like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/63M29f28X0i) to avoid unnecessary complexity for querying.

---

Nevertheless, for your current situation, you can use `$objectToArray` for querying.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "certificates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$certificates",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$c"
          }
        }
      },
      "raw": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "certificates": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$certificates",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "certificates.v.expiryDate": {
        "$lte": "2023-09-14"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$raw"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EZ45hpkPFyg)

Comment: A key point that's not currently stated directly here is that there is no method to achieve '_efficient filtering_' with the current schema